# Azure Function 2.0 Dependency injection error

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-durable-functions

Before the Azure Function 3.0 my app is working properly but after the Microsoft update. The Function application doesn't work even if I deploy it on Azure it will return the dependency injection error. Why would MS upgrade version that break existing one? I'm really frustrated.
[image]

Comment: Can you show the .csproj file and Startup.cs of your function?

Comment: So what version of Azure Functions are you using?

Comment: Here's my packages and I'm using V2: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.30" />

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall/update the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
```

Comment: It didn't solve the V2 issue. I just updated the Function app to V3.